Dishwasher control board not delivering expected 120VAC to water valve, dishwasher not filling with water
I have a Kitchen Aid dishwasher model KUDE40FXSP4 which does NOT fill with water.

I tested the existing water valve in my garage by supplying 120V AC directly to it from an external source of electricity. The water valve works perfectly when supplied with the expected voltage - water from a hosed connection flows freely and at a very high rate.

I re-installed the water valve and conducted a multimeter test of the VAC delivered from the control board to the water value during a wash cycle.  It delivers ~2.7VAC and NO water flows into the dishwasher unit. The water value is rated for 120 VAC so I decided to replace the control board.  I paid RepairClinic $200 for the new control board. I installed  it and there is still only 2.7V AC getting from the control board to the water valve. Water does not enter the dishwasher at all during a cycle.

There is no blockage in the tubes, and the copper water pipe delivers water at a very high rate as expected when not connected to anything.

A continuity test of the wire connector itself (connects between the control board and the water valve) is successful. There is electrical continuity in the wire connector itself.


Given I cannot return this $200 purchase does anybody have a professional suggestion as to what might be going-on so that the $200 I paid isn't for naught?

This question is off-topic here. You'll be better-off asking on a dishwasher repair forum.

maybe there is no 120 Vac being supplied to the board

there is still only 2.7V AC getting from the control board to the water valve ... what is the point of item 3?

I was just making the point that the problem is purely electrical and has nothing to do with the water flow itself.

The problem clearly wasn't the control board. Since it works identically to your original control board, you can sell it for $200, and troubleshoot further where the problem is. Or, whatever the problem is, it may have blown up two control boards now and both are damaged. May we suggest calling an authorized repair center to fix it for you, or buy a new one?

Could be as simple as the overfill float switch or something of that nature. Suggest you watch some DIY repair videos on your model (or similar) and you'll quickly get an idea. Dishwashers are not particularly complicated.
